# How to pass multiple JavaScript data variables in a jQuery ajax() call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, parameter-passing

If `startDateTime` & `endDateTime` have are dateTime values along the lines of this:

```
Start: Mon Jan 10 2011 18:15:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
End: Mon Jan 10 2011 18:45:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
```

How do you pass both `startDateTime` & `endDateTime` to the ajax call below?

```
eventNew : function(calEvent, event) 
{
    var startDateTime = calEvent.start;
    var endDateTime = calEvent.end;
    jQuery.ajax(
    {
        url: '/eventnew/',
        cache: false,
        data: /** How to pass startDateTime & endDateTime here? */,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response)
        {
            // do something with response
        }
    });         

},
```

Answer (score 13):

Try:

```
data: {
    start: startDateTime,
    end: endDateTime
}
```

This will create request parameters of 'start' and 'end' on the server that you can use.

The `{...}` is an [object literal](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/obj_lit.php), which is an easy way to create objects. The [`.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function takes the object and translates its properties (in this case, 'start' and 'end') into key/value pairs that are set as properties on the HTTP request that gets sent to the server.

Answer (score 7):

```
data: {
    startDateTime : "xxx",
    endDateTime : "yyy"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the values in JSON notation:

```
data: {startDateTime: 'value here ', endDateTime: 'value here '}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

data: JSON.stringify({ start: startDateTime, end: endDateTime })

Answer (score 0):

in the data

```
ajax({
    url : //your file url finshed with **,**
    data : {Start: Mon Jan 10 2011 18:15:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time),
           End: Mon Jan 10 2011 18:45:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)}, //finish with **,**
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(response)
    {
        // do something with response
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ajax({
     url : //your file url finshed with ,
     data : {
         Start: Mon Jan 10 2011 18:15:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time),
         End: Mon Jan 10 2011 18:45:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
     },
     type: 'POST',
     success: function(response) { 
         // do something with response 
     }
});
```